# Simulation VS Analytical Results of Outage Probability:

Tags: r, matlab, simulation, probability, distribution

I want to find the outage of a node in decode-and-forward (DF) relay.

Mathematically, I want to find

```
 Pr(min(SNR_R, SNR_D)<SNR_{thr})
```

which in probabilistic terms is equal to

```
Pr(min(X,Y)< x) = F_X(x) + F_Y(x) - F_X(x)F_Y(x)
```

I have derived the analytical expressions for both `F_X(x)` and `F_Y(x)`, and both of them separately matches with the simulation results. Which means if I plot the `Pr(SNR_R<SNR_{thr})` it matches the CDF `F_X(x)` and similarly if I plot the `Pr(SNR_D<SNR_{thr})` it matches the CDF `F_Y(x)`. However, when I try to plot Eq. `(1)` and `(2)` together, they don't match.

**UPDATE:** When I calculate the outage separately and plot them using eq.2 it matches. e.g. lets assume

```
poutR=SNR_R<SNR_{thr}
poutD=SNR_D<SNR_{thr}
```

and then plot

```
pout=poutR + poutD - poutR*poutD
```

it exactly matches the analytical results derived using

```
Pr(min(X,Y)< x) = F_X(x) + F_Y(x) - F_X(x)F_Y(x).
```

My question is: Is it correct to plot the simulation results like this? and what is the reason behind this?

Any help in this regard will be very much appreciated.

Comment: Are X and Y independent?  Deriving Eq. 2 requires independence.

Comment: Another possible source of error - `<` only works if X and Y are continuous, `<=` is required if either or both are discrete.

Comment: Yes both of them are independent and continuous. If I calculate the simulation results using Eq. 2 it exactly matches. But I am not sure if it is correct to use it. I have updated the question with more detail.